# WebLogic 12.2 to 12.1 lost endpoints

Tags: java, rest, weblogic12c

Hello it's relative simple. I began my project on weblogic 12.2, but now i have received the news from my boss that this will be install on 12.1.3 for be specific. But making some test i found that the endpoint rest that i had generated on 12.2 doesn't work on 12.1.3 can someone say me why...

This i one of my services:

```
 package xxxxxx
 import package.DdcEstado;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.ejb.Stateless;
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;
 import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;


@Stateless
@Path("estados")
public class DdcEstadoFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<DdcEstado> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "Data_Delaer_CentralizerPU")
private EntityManager em;

public DdcEstadoFacadeREST() {
    super(DdcEstado.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(DdcEstado entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void edit(@PathParam("id") BigDecimal id, DdcEstado entity) {
    super.edit(entity);
}

@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
public void remove(@PathParam("id") BigDecimal id) {
    super.remove(super.find(id));
}

@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public DdcEstado find(@PathParam("id") BigDecimal id) {
    return super.find(id);
}

@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<DdcEstado> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}

@GET
@Path("{from}/{to}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<DdcEstado> findRange(@PathParam("from") Integer from, @PathParam("to") Integer to) {
    return super.findRange(new int[]{from, to});
}

@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String countREST() {
    return String.valueOf(super.count());
}

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

}
```

This is the ApplicationConfig:

```
package gt.com.pckg.service;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

@Override
public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
}

/**
 * Do not modify addRestResourceClasses() method.
 * It is automatically populated with
 * all resources defined in the project.
 * If required, comment out calling this method in getClasses().
 */
private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcAlarmaFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcColaDetalleFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcColaFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcDealerFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcEstadoFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcProcesoFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcProgramacionFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcPuntoVentaFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcRolFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.DdcUsuarioFacadeREST.class);
    resources.add(gt.com.pckg.service.ProcessExecutor.class);
}

}
```

In this case when you enter to localhost:7001/proyect/rest/estados i get a 404 response.

I will really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have found the solution, and this is very simple.

There a re so many diferences on the sintaxis and instructions of the end points on 12.1.3 and 12.2.1 Why?

Well because Oracle say we are going to do that on this form...

For example the MediaTypes on 12.2.1 you set them like http header "application/json" but on the 12.1.3 you yet use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON

and there are other thnigs like the ApplicationConfig that have some changes....

My solution was set the project the new server version and on netbeans generate the endpoints again from the database.